# When you have 2 sites, front end and a rest api, how/where do you store uploaded images?

Tags: rest, vue.js, asp.net-core, file-upload

I have 2 different sites basically. 1 is a rest api, the other is the front end built in vue.

Actually uploading a file isn't the issue. My question is how to have the Vue portion access the files that were uploaded via rest.

Should I save the files to c:...VueProjectFolder\images (could use some code help if this is the case)? Or should the Vue site be inside the rest api folder for relative access? Or is it better to save relative, then move the uploaded files? Or do I have vue access the files via the rest api address?

None really seem like the right answer and I'm failing with google atm.

Down the road, I would expect them to be served from a mapped drive as there will be many. Mostly images, but also sound files.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a Vue or 'two sites' issue. This is an architecture issue, and like such issues, It depends. What I can do is tell you how I approached a similar situation.

1. I uploaded the files normally
2. I renamed them, created a folder structure based on the year, month, and day the picture was uploaded. Then I moved the image to the permanent location. So an image uploaded today will be located at `.../assets/images/2020/09/01/randomImageName.png` for instance.
3. I stored the image location along with whatever resource came with the uploaded image in the database.

Now in my frontend, I do a normal api call for a particular resource and it spits out everything about that resource, including the image location.

I think I should point out that my case was an ecommerce website with a REST API endpoint servicing the frontend requests. Generally this approach is advised since you can take advantage of backing up the image directory, backing up the database and easily moving between servers if need be.

This may not exactly be your case, but I hope it gives you insight into how to approach this efficiently.

Comment: Agreed, this isn't Vue, but it's my first utilizing a front end framework completely separate from the back end. Always been mvc/api in the same project/folder. If I'm understanding you correctly, you save the files local to your api project and access them that way also. You wouldn't store the images in your front end site (ang/vue/react)?

Comment: Yeah the image is stored on the same server in the backend. But it could also be stored in your frontend server as well.It really doesn't matter where the image is stored, it could even be stored in AWS S3 buckets, or be pulled from filehosting sites. The major thing is knowing the location of the image. So you can store on the frontend server, but if its a dynamic app then you need to at least store the location of the images somehow. And that is usually done with a database